# SQL Counting on characters

Tags: sql, count

I want to use an SQL statement that returns the department number, department name and the number of employees for each department that has less than 4 employees grouping by department number and department name. I have inputted sample data

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Departments
(
First_Name NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
Last_Name NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
Job_Description VARCHAR(30) NULL,
Department_Name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
Department_Number INT NOT NULL,
Date_Hired DATE NOT NULL,
);

INSERT INTO dbo.Departments(First_Name,Last_Name,Job_Description,Department_Name,Department_Number,Date_Hired)
VALUES
('Niel','Matthews','Sales Representative','Marketing',80,'1990-06-12'),
('Jerome','Daniels','Sales Representative','Accounting',60,'1973-03-30'),
('Caleb','Sewcharran','Employee','Accounting',35,'1986-08-10'),
('Orion','Wolf','Employee','Marketing',80,'1987-10-04'),
('Gaige','Johnson','Employee','Accounting',60,'1992-09-22'),
('Maya','Heller','Employee','Marketing',25,'1989-06-17'),
('James','Maroon','Employee','Accounting',30,'2011-08-22'),
('Alex','Mercer','Employee','Accounting',60,'2010-03-17'),
('Adam','Beecher','Sales Representative','Marketing',80,'2012-10-04'),
('Bruce','Wayne','Employee','Marketing',25,'2012-08-12'),
('Al','Kepler','Sales Representative','Accounting',80,'1973-06-30');
```

I have also attempted an SQL statement but it does not work

```
SELECT Department_Number,Department_Name,Job_Description 
FROM dbo.Departments
WHERE Job_Description='Employee'
(SELECT DISTINCT Department_Name FROM dbo.Departments,
    (SELECT CAST('Marketing'AS INT)AS Least_Employees,
                CAST('Accounting'AS INT)AS Least_Least_Employees)AS Least_Employees
                WHERE Department_Name>4 OR Department_Name>4)
                GROUP BY Department_Name AND Department_Number;
```

Appreciate it if you would tell me what i could have used to get on the right track.

Comment: Your tables don't make sense.  Don't you have a lookup table for departments?  How do you represent a department with no employees?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY` clause :

```
SELECT Department_Number, Department_Name, COUNT(*) AS NoofEmp
FROM dbo.Departments d
WHERE ob_Description = 'Employee'
GROUP B YDepartment_Number,Department_Name
HAVING COUNT(*) <= 4;
```